# How to check which button (in fxml) has invoked a function in controller.java when both buttons have same onAction method

Tags: java, javafx

If there are multiple buttons in an fxml file, with the sam onAction method , how to check which button has invoked the method in the controller.java file.

Fxml code is like this

```xml
<Button fx:id="b12", onAction="#push">
<Button fx:id="b13", onAction="#push">
```

Controller.java looks like this

```
@FXML
Button   b12,  b13;
```

I want to write a function such that if it is invoked by the first button , then its id has to be printed and otherwise the second id.

Comment: Use [`EventObject.getSource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()). In JavaFX the source is always the object which the `EventHandler` was registered on (during execution of that `EventHandler`).

Comment: Needless to say that you may be better of using different event handlers...(Assuming you don't have too many of those buttons; in that case you may be better of using a loop in the `initialize` method to create all those buttons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Slaw mentioned in their comment, you would want to use the `EventObject.getSource()` method to determine which object triggered the event.

Here is a simple application to demonstrate the details. There are 3 files in this example:

**Main.java** - Simply starts the application

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Just loads the sample GUI
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Layout.fxml"));
            loader.setController(new Controller());

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));

            primaryStage.setTitle("Event Source Sample");
            primaryStage.setWidth(300);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller.java** - Provides the code to handle interactions with the UI

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Controller {

    // Declare the controls used in the FXML file
    @FXML
    private Button button1;
    @FXML
    private Button button2;
    @FXML
    private Button button3;
    @FXML
    private Label lblSource;

    // This method is called when any of the buttons in the FXML file is clicked
    // The "ActionEvent" parameter includes all the details of the event that calls this method
    @FXML
    void handleClick(ActionEvent event) {

        // Assuming only a Button will call this method, determine which button it was by retrieving the Source of
        // the event.
        Button sourceButton = (Button) event.getSource();

        // We have the source, so let's update the label to show the text of the Button that was clicked.
        lblSource.setText(sourceButton.getText());
    }
}
```

**Layout.fxml** - The actual FXML design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>
    <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0">
        <Button fx:id="button1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleClick" text="Button 1"/>
        <Button fx:id="button2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleClick" text="Button 2"/>
        <Button fx:id="button3" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleClick" text="Button 3"/>
    </HBox>
    <Label text="Source:"/>
    <Label fx:id="lblSource"/>
</VBox>
```

---

The main code to be concerned with is in the `Controller.java` class. You'll see the `handleClick(ActionEvent event)` method, which is called by each of the `Button` nodes in the FXML file.

When the method is called, it receives an `ActionEvent` object. We can then determine which `Button` created the event by calling the `ActionEvent.getSource()` method. From there, you can do any processing needed based on the source.

Comment: Now its working. I was using                                           import java.awt.event.ActionEvent                            instead of                                                                        import javafx.event.ActionEvent