# How to know which button is bieng clicked in javafx

Tags: java, button, javafx

How to know which button has envoked the function. I have read **other answers** on **stackoverflow** [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456418/how-to-check-which-button-in-fxml-has-invoked-a-function-in-controller-java-wh) . I tried creating a new button and giving it a value of `event.getSource()` but it is not working

```
    @FXML
    Button v1;
    @FXML
    Button v2;
    @FXML
    Button v3;
    @FXML
    Button v4;
    @FXML
    Button v5;
    @FXML
    Button v6;


public void printButton(ActionEvent event){

            Button sourceButton = (Button) event.getSource();

            if(sourceButton == v1){
                System.out.print("v1");
            }

            else if(sourceButton == v2){
                System.out.print("v2");
            }

            else if(sourceButton == v3){
                System.out.print("v3");
            }

            else if(sourceButton == v4){
                System.out.print("v4");
            }

            else if(sourceButton == v5){
                System.out.print("v5");
            }

            else if(sourceButton == v6){
                System.out.print("v6");
            }
        }
```

I have created the button in **fxml** and it calls the same function **printButton();**

Comment: There's no copy constructor for `Button`. However: How do you know the code is not working? The only thing you do is assigning some field, no output to the console, no modification of the scene... There's no way we can help here without more info.  
(Voting for close)

Comment: if you made your fxml right, then your code should work..please post your fxml too.. Btw I personally would compare Buttons with button.equals(otherButton)

Comment: @micpog90 Comparing with button.equals(otherButton) worked.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is using java 8 update 211 for testing.

The comments are suggesting that changing `==` to `.equals()` was the solution to this. However, Button does not override `.equals()`, so both of those ways are doing effectively the same thing.

Running up the sample application below to test resulted in all of the 3 buttons working as expected. Therefore, there may have been something incorrect in the FXML file with OP's code, which (as I write this) has not been shown from OP.

In the example below, note that the fxml file:

- Specifies the controller with `fx:controller="sample.Controller"`
- Contains 3 buttons with their ids matching exactly to the ones declared in Controller
- On each button, includes `onAction="#printButton"` , and the name in quotes matches the method name in Controller `onAction="#printButton"`.

---

Please note all of these are within the same package.

Main.java:

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```java
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    Button v1;
    @FXML
    Button v2;
    @FXML
    Button v3;

    public void printButton(ActionEvent event){

        Button sourceButton = (Button) event.getSource();

        if(sourceButton.equals(v1)){
            System.out.print("v1");
        }

        else if(sourceButton == v2){
            System.out.print("v2");
        }

        else if(sourceButton == v3){
            System.out.print("v3");
        }

    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>
    <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0">
        <Button fx:id="v1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#printButton" text="Button 1"/>
        <Button fx:id="v2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#printButton" text="Button 2"/>
        <Button fx:id="v3" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#printButton" text="Button 3"/>
    </HBox>
    <Label text="Source:"/>
    <Label fx:id="lblSource"/>
</VBox>
```

Comment: yes, changing ".equals()" to "==" is working now. Maybe something else was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

make your life easy how about using  `isPressed()`  function ?

```
                 if( v1.isPressed() )  {
                 name2 = n1.getText(); 

               System.out.println("   V1  got called ");
                 }
```

`v1.isPressed();`  means check whether v1 has been clicked or not it return true or false

i'm not sure about also   `v1.isfire();` I think this one can make auto click

Comment: Where should i check it. I cannot check it in the printButton() function.